# Loading asp:chart from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

The following logic runs onload of the web page and calls a partial view to display data in the chart:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("_GetChartDetails", "Chart", new { chartType = "Won" })' id="chartid" />
```

this works.

but when I do it from javascript the image is blank. Could anyone advice what I could be doing wrong?

```
$http.get("http://localhost:51666/Chart/_GetChartDetails?chartType=Loss")
.success(function (response) {

    alert(response);

    //$("#chartid").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + response);

    document.getElementById("chartid").src = response;

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    alert(data);

});
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nope, but this doesn't make sense cause the MVC controller gets called from the javascript above. I am not sure if javascript converts the response data type to something else that an <img src can not read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually doing an `$http.get` to generate the chart why don't you just change the image source to point to the partial view and pass through the required parameter (Won or Lost):

```
$scope.GetChartDetails = function (chartType) {

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = "/Chart/_GetChartDetails?chartType=" + chartType;

    var node = document.getElementById('chart');

    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }

    document.getElementById('chart').appendChild(img);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your if the image is correct defined:

```
.success(function (response) {
 var image = document.createElement('img');
 image.onload = function () {
  //if it's correct created you can open it in console (click)and see what your server returns, it may be the correct response but you may have issues with CSS.
  console.log(image);
 };
 image.src = response;
}
```

Console clickable image:
[image]